# C Access element of Enum without declaring variable

Tags: c, enums

Lets say I have the enum in C:

```
enum TYPE {
    varOne = 1,
    varTwo = 2,
    varThree = 3
};
```

How would I access an element of this enum without declaring a variable like so:

```
enum TYPE variable = 1;
```

so I could do something like:

```
if(otherVariable == TYPE.varONE)
```

Comment: Your enum is not valid C.

Comment: Enums are integral types, not character-strings

Answer (score 3):

The names of `enum` constants are visible globally, so you can just do this:

```
if(otherVariable == varONE)
```

Also, `enum` constants have integer type, so it doesn't make sense to assign strings to them.  It should look something like this:

```
enum TYPE {
    varOne = 1,
    varTwo = 2,
    varThree = 3
};
```

If you need to gets the strings associated with these values, you need a separate function for that:

```
const char *TYPE_STR(enum TYPE v)
{
    switch (v) {
    case varOne:
        return "One";
    case varTwo:
        return "Two";
    case varThree:
        return "Three";
    default:
        return "(invalid)";
    }
}
```